# Why do I get "Error: Could not find or load main class" for any java code?

Tags: java

Any java code I compile and try to execute from CMD line results in the error: 
**Error: Could not find or load main class**

I have tried setting environment variables:
PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202

and with and with out:
CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib  or
CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\rt.jar or
CLASSPATH=(directory of code)

The following is an example of a simple test prog that will not run:

```
/**
 * Experiment with println() and print()
 */
public class HelloGoodbye 
{   
    public static void main(String[] args) 
     { 
        System.out.println("My First Hello!");
        System.out.println("Hello again!");
        System.out.print("Hello finally!");
        System.out.print("Goodbye!");
    }
}
```

This produces:
    Error: Could not find or load main class

Comment: what did you type in the cmd ?

Comment: javac HelloGoodbye.java  which works to create HelloGoodbye.class then java HelloGoodbye.class which gives me the error

Comment: run java HelloGoodbye instead of java HelloGoodbye.class

Comment: run command java HelloGoodBye.java and not java HelloGoodBye.class

Comment: [Solved] *facepalm* I have been staying up too late. Thank you all for the help. You guys are great! I got so tunnel visioned on the problem I overlooked the basics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to compile your code:

```
javac HelloGoodbye
```

A class file will be created (HelloGoodbye.class). Then, you have to run the following command for running the program:

```
java HelloGoodbye
```